# How to merge tag “Kalman-filters” and tag “Kalman” into one tag, such as “Kalman-filters”?

Tags: support

After going through all the questions from tag `Kalman-filters` and tag `Kalman`, I found that they're talking about the same thing? How could I merge them into one tag, such as `Kalman-filters`?

Comment: Let me dig. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried again, with the same result.  As  there were only 9 questions with the tag `kalman` I've deleted these tags and, where the question did not have it already, added the tag `kalman-filters`.

Hopefully `kalman` [will disappear at 03:00 UTC today.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/131640)

---

I've just tried, as moderator, to merge these two tags... but I get an "Ooops" error message. Let's see if anything comes of it.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, try it later.